# How to Speed up a query that filters data by date and time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

i am working with a database that is already in production, that means the table can not be changed.

I need to filter data by date and time, nevertheless the date and time values are not stored as a Datetime2 but to a NVARCHARMAX, the database has a poor design because allows multiple keys refering to the same object with different values, for example:

| ID | Barcode | DateTimeTestFinished | tester | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | '2021-01-01' | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | AA | '2021-01-02' | 2 | 17 |

In the table above they are speaking about the same product (barcode) but with different test values.

The main requirements is to find the last (unique) test result from the product, so all being said i wrote the following query:

```
select count(l.Barcode) as total,m.Result, m.Tester
from 
(select * from (select  Barcode, max(convert(datetime2, DateTimeTestFinished ,103)) as 'mostrecent'

from AdBlue_EOL Group by Barcode) k  where k.mostrecent > '2020-01-01')l left join 
(
    select Barcode, Tester, Result, max(convert(datetime2, DateTimeTestFinished ,103)) as 'mostrecent' 
    from AdBlue_EOL group by Barcode,Tester, Result
)m on l.Barcode = m.Barcode and l.mostrecent=m.mostrecent group by m.Tester,m.Result
```

The query is working, nevertheless  it is taking too much time to process (Approximately 2 minutes for 3 million rows), as i am not a database expert i do not know what can be causing such a delay, is this delay normal? i really appreciate any help, comment or suggestion.

I am using MSSQL

Query Plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJzREWoEj

Thank you in Advance

Miguel

Comment: i mean that the table can not be modified because the client wants to be compatible with previous backups, new things can be added to the database at the end the aim is to have a query that can retrieve the data in a more efficient way

Comment: i have review one more time the table and it appear to not be working with indexes

Comment: I am using Sql server 2019, above in the edited question you will find the execution file, in the original query the variable names are differnet i just represented in an easy way in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary issue appears to be lack of indexing.

Looking at your query, the following index should work for you

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX
ON AdBlue_EOL (Barcode, Tester, Result) INCLUDE (DateTimeTestFinished)
```

However, it also appears you can make your query more efficient by utilizing window functions.

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  eol.Result,
  eol.Tester
FROM (
    SELECT
      eol.Barcode,
      eol.Tester,
      eol.Result,
      CONVERT(datetime2, eol.DateTimeTestFinished, 103) AS mostrecent,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eol.Barcode 
          ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime2, eol.DateTimeTestFinished, 103) DESC) AS rn
    FROM AdBlue_EOL eol
) eol
WHERE eol.rn = 1
  AND eol.mostrecent > '20200101'
GROUP BY
  eol.Tester,
  eol.Result;
```

I would *strongly* recommend that you change the `DateTimeTestFinished` to be a `datetime2` column. But barring that, you can hack it with a computed column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE AdBlue_EOL
  ADD DateTime2TestFinished AS CONVERT(datetime2, DateTimeTestFinished, 103);
```

And change the index to

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX
ON AdBlue_EOL (Barcode, DateTime2TestFinished DESC) INCLUDE (Tester, Result)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

---

Final note: formatting and spacing your query properly aids readability, and therefore comprehension.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tested your query without any indexing and improve the executing time, now the executing time is around 12 seconds, which is acceptable, nevertheless i am creating a test DB to benchmark with indexes and correct datatypes, maybe the client will accept to change the table, just for other people trying to test this approach, there is a Typing error in your query instead of m.Result and m.Tester, eol.Result and eol.Tester must be written